# Lightning Lookup Component - Icon out of Input when having label

Tags: lightning-aura-components, css, html, slds, icon

I have implemented a generic lookup component. The issue that i am facing is that i cannot find a way to "move" inside the lightning input my lightning icon. Any ideas? Code Below:

```
<!--Component-->
    <div class="slds-form-element__control">
        <div class="slds-combobox_container slds-has-inline-listbox slds-input-has-icon slds-input-has-icon slds-input-has-icon_left-right">
            <div aura:id="divLookup"
                 class="slds-combobox slds-dropdown-trigger slds-dropdown-trigger_click slds-combobox-lookup"
                 aria-expanded="false" aria-haspopup="listbox" role="combobox slds-input-has-icon slds-input-has-icon slds-input-has-icon_left-right" >
                <span class="slds-icon_container slds-icon-utility-search slds-input__icon iconheight">
                    <lightning:icon class="slds-icon slds-icon slds-icon_small slds-icon-text-default" iconName="{!v.lookupIcon}" size="x-small" alternativeText="icon" />
                </span> 
                <div class="slds-combobox__form-element">
                            <lightning:input type="search"
                                             aura:id="searchinput"
                                             required="{!v.required}"
                                             fieldLevelHelp="{!v.fieldLevelHelp}"
                                             label="{!v.fieldLabel}"
                                             name="{!v.fieldLabel}"
                                             readonly="{!v.readOnly}"
                                             disabled="{!v.disabled}"
                                             value="{!v.selectedRecordName}"
                                             onchange="{!c.handleSearchRecords}"
                                             isLoading="false"
                                             placeholder="{!v.placeholder}"
                                             onfocus="{!c.handleSearchRecords}"
                                             onblur="{!c.hideList}"
                                             class="leftspace"/>
                        </div> 
                <div id="listbox-unique-id" role="listbox">
                    <ul class="slds-listbox slds-listbox_vertical slds-dropdown slds-dropdown_fluid" role="presentation">
                        <aura:iteration var="rec" items="{!v.matchingRecords}">
                            <c:el_sObjectLookupItem record="{!rec}" subHeadingFieldsAPI="{!v.subHeadingFieldsAPI}" iconCategoryName="{!v.lookupIcon}"/>
                        </aura:iteration>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

My Component is shown as below, and i want to find a way to have the icon inside my lightning input.
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For customizing elements as you are, it is recommeded to use the SLDS blueprints and tweak the code/css as needed. example,

```
<div class="slds-form-element">
        <label class="slds-form-element__label" for="text-input-id-1">Input Label</label>
        <div class="slds-form-element__control slds-input-has-icon slds-input-has-icon_left">
            <svg class="slds-icon slds-input__icon slds-input__icon_left slds-icon-text-default" aria-hidden="true">
                <use xlink:href="/assets/icons/standard-sprite/svg/symbols.svg#record_update"></use>
            </svg>
            <svg class="slds-icon slds-input__icon slds-input__icon_left slds-icon-text-default" aria-hidden="true">
                <use xlink:href="/assets/icons/utility-sprite/svg/symbols.svg#search"></use>
            </svg>
            <input type="search" id="text-input-id-1" placeholder="Placeholder text…" class="slds-input" />
        </div>
    </div>
```

the above is an extract from the [slds blueprints](https://www.lightningdesignsystem.com/components/input/) with 2 icons within the "input" element. the only thing left to do is add [margins](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_margin.asp) to the elements so the 2 icons are properly placed within the input  as well as a margin to the input element, so the placeholder does not overlap with the icons.
[image]